# Superset LDAP Auth with AD ERROR 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: authentication, active-directory, flask-login, apache-superset

We are trying to connect superset with our AD server. Everything Worked fine but when we login with AD credentials, It's showing Invlid Credential and in superset logs I'm able to see the below error.

```
2022-10-11 16:59:54,961:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.manager:{'result': -1, 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server", 'errno': 104, 'ctrls': [], 'info': 'Connection reset by peer'}
```

Comment: Sounds like a network issue.

Comment: AUTH_TYPE = 2
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = False
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "uid"
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldaps:xxxxxx.in"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "OU=...,DC=in"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "CN=......DC=in"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx"

Comment: I've used these configs. Do i need to do something else apart from adding config ? Like some cert need or adding hostname where superset is running in AD host?

Comment: For `AUTH_LDAP_SERVER`, you're missing the `//`. It should be `"ldaps://xxxxxx.in"`. It's possible that it's a certificate issue. You can try using `AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED` and see if it works. If it does, then that's the issue. You can use the `AUTH_LDAP_TLS_*` options to set the keyfile options. I've never used Superset or Flask, so I can't help much more. I'm just going by the options listed [here](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html)

Comment: It still could be a network issue if a firewall is blocking the default LDAPS port 636